# Looking for a more elegant DO WHILE solution

Tags: c#, do-while

So I have some code centered around a do while loop.

```
string token;
var count = 0;      
var checkDataLength= data.Length == 16;

do
{              
    count = 0;
    token = GenerateToken(data, start, end);

    if (checkDataLength)
    {
        if (Mod120Check(token))
        {                      
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    if (IsCompliant(token))
    {
        count += 1;
    }
} 
while (count > 0);

return token;
```

Basically, I am generating a token and for this token to be valid, has to FAIL the Mod120Check and the IsCompliant check.  I cannot change how those methods return the data.

While the above code works, I feel that its ugly and I was wondering if anyone had a better way of doing it?

Thanks

Comment: I feel this is the best way. Other solutions would be uglier. It matches your requirement which is to execute it atleast once.

Comment: I don't find anything bad about this code. The only thing that I would improve is the use of the `count` variable. It's not a count at all! It should be a simple boolean flag.

Comment: @Alejandro I'd say Nathalia's answer makes this code look pretty bad by comparison :)

Comment: Fugly loops tend to be fixable with `for (;;) {}` + `break`.  The explicit break makes it easy to reason about the flow and debug the break condition.  You might like `continue` in this case as well.  Some programmers might consider `for (;;)` too grating, but nothing screams loop-forever louder :)

Answer (score 17):

Try this:

```
do
{
    token = GenerateToken(data, start, end);
} 
while (checkDataLength && Mod120Check(token) || IsCompliant(token))
```

Just moving your conditions to the `while`.

**(!)** Notice that `IsCompliant(token)` will only be called if `checkDataLength && Mod120Check(token)` states `false`. It shouldn't cause any colateral effects, but it could, depending on what your `IsCompliant` method does.

Comment: Much neater! The OP may want to note that in the case where the `Mod120Check` passes, the original code still calls `IsCompliant` whereas this rewrite does not. This is almost certainly another point in the rewrite's favor, but worth pointing out just in case that call has some goofy side effects or something.

Comment: @JoeFarrell Good point! i hadn't noticed this detail. Added it to the answer

Answer (score 2):

You're right, it is ugly.  You are using `count` in an unexpected way (it gets reset to zero at the top of every loop, and can go positive for two different reasons).  When I see `count`, I expect something to start at zero and count up (or start high and count done).  Try this instead:

- Change `var count = 0;` to `var goodEnough = false;` up at the top
- Remove the `count = 0;` statement
- Change the two `count += 1;` statements to `goodEnough = true;`
- Change the `while (count > 0);` to `while (!goodEnough);`

This emphasizes that you are starting in a "not good enough" state, and you will loop until some condition makes it good enough to continue past the loop.